# raspbian + libavcodec + which source repository

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, debian, apt, ffmpeg

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 which is running Raspbian (Noobs 1.9.2).

I'm able to install the libavcodev-dev package with the following command:

`sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev`

It seems libavcodec can be coming from two developers. (Libav or FFmpeg team)

I would like to know from which implementation is the package coming from ?

How can I know the details of the apt "libavcodec-dev" package for raspbian. (like what version and which source files were used to build it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-cache show libavcodec-dev`

Answer (score 2):

Another method similar to the one mentioned by @thingian is `apt-cache policy package_name`
It will show something like this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt-cache policy emacs
emacs:
  Installed: 46.1
  Candidate: 46.1
  Version table:
 *** 46.1 0
        500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

As you can see this shows the website it is from from which you should be able to tell *who* it's from.